# Too many numbers in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I have saved a bit locker pin somewhere in 30GB worth of PSTs in Outlook. Is there a way to do an advanced search to find the pin, like ***** - ***** - *****?

Comment: powergrep and regex https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression https://www.powergrep.com/

Comment: Challenge me when you are ready to duel a god

Comment: so for example something like `[0-9]*\-[0-9]*\-[0-9]*` would match 872-98749-2834 https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/regular_expressions.png

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do an advanced search to find the pin, like ***** - ***** - *****?

Not feasible using the native features available in Outlook. Outlook doesn't support regex in the built-in search options.

If you are familiar with vba script, you can take a look at the article below and adjust the regex pattern based on your need:
[Use RegEx to extract text from an Outlook email message](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/regex-parse-message-text/).

You can use the link below to help generate the regular expression:
https://regex101.com/r/5YOJnG/1
Based on my test, seems like (\d{5}-\d{5}-\d{5}) can be used for your case.

Comment: thats just a worse version of the answer i gave in the comments above